# How to create a scrolling text view that snaps to position

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm trying to create a feature similar to that on Headspace where they have a scrolling text view that snaps into position (then returns a value).

Fundamentally what would be the best way to achieve this in Java/Android?

Would it be to use ViewPager2 (but this seems rather complex for something so simple) or to use a RecyclerView (but then you have the complexity of integrating snapping to positions and returning the value)?

I feel there must be a simple and effective way of doing this that I'm missing.

[image: Headspace time choice]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with using a Recyclerview [SnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/SnapHelper).

```
val snapHelper = LinearSnapHelper()
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rv_items)
```

Have a look on [this article](https://medium.com/over-engineering/detecting-snap-changes-with-androids-recyclerview-snaphelper-9e9f5e95c424) for getting the snapped view, specifically this bit:

```
override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        if (behavior == Behavior.NOTIFY_ON_SCROLL) {
            maybeNotifySnapPositionChange(recyclerView)
        }
    }
override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
    if (behavior == Behavior.NOTIFY_ON_SCROLL_STATE_IDLE
            && newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        maybeNotifySnapPositionChange(recyclerView)
    }
}

private fun maybeNotifySnapPositionChange(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
    val snapPosition = snapHelper.getSnapPosition(recyclerView)
    val snapPositionChanged = this.snapPosition != snapPosition
    if (snapPositionChanged) {
        onSnapPositionChangeListener?.onSnapPositionChange(snapPosition)
        this.snapPosition = snapPosition
    }
}
```

Even though the code is in Kotlin, the methods are the same and you can get an idea how to implement this.

Another solution, if there're not too much data, is using a [NumberPicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker):

```
private fun showPicker() {
        val d: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        val inflater = this.layoutInflater
        val dialogView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_picker, null)
        val numberPicker =
            dialogView.findViewById<View>(R.id.numberPicker) as NumberPicker
        numberPicker.maxValue = 50
        numberPicker.minValue = 1
        numberPicker.wrapSelectorWheel = false
        d.setTitle("Set duration")
            .setView(dialogView)
            .setPositiveButton(
                "Done"
            ) { _, _ ->
                duration = numberPicker.value
            }
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.general_cancel) { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.cancel()
            }
            .create().show()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! NumberPicker is the exact thing I was looking for